# How can I filter objects by how many objects reference them?

Tags: python, django

Let's say I'm building an Article / Comment system like this:

```
class Article(models.Model):
    title = models.TextField()
    content = models.TextField()

class Comment(models.Model):
    article = ForeignKey(Article)
    content = models.TextField()
```

How can I filter `Article.objects` to find the articles that have more than ten comments?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to [annotate](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/aggregation/#generating-aggregates-for-each-item-in-a-queryset) your queryset with the number of comments for each article, then filter on the annotated field.

```
from django.db.models import Count
Article.objects.annotate(num_comments=Count('comment')).filter(num_comments__gt=10)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
from django.db.models import Count

Article.objects.annotate(comment_count=Count('comment')).filter(comment_count__gte=10)
```

Answer (score 1):

See this sample from https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/aggregation/#aggregating-annotations:

```
 Book.objects.annotate(num_authors=Count('authors')).filter(num_authors__gt=1)
```